# Which criteria should one look at when purchasing an electric toothbrush?

Tags: dentistry, toothbrush

Which criteria should one look at when purchasing an electric toothbrush (from a medical perspective, i.e. ignoring non-medical criteria such as price, battery, life expectancy or warranty), and what's at the optimal value for each of these criteria?

Some ideas of criteria:

- number of brush strokes per minute
- vibration mode
- shape of the brush (see below for some examples)

If the question is too broad,  I don't mind asking about each criterion in separate questions (though I might not be aware of all the criteria).

---

Examples of shapes of the brush:

[image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbcMuj
- https://redd.it/70rfce

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the [Cochrane Systematic review] about this issue, available at [1]http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD002281.pub3/full#CD002281-tbl-0012